# Insert Time in table from a text file

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and created a table named **TransactionTimes**, it has a column transtime it's datatype is **Time**.
I want to insert data from a text file in it.

My issue is, after inserting data, I checked it in my table using select query and it shows time like **00:12:46** which was **1246** in my text file.

in short my text file have data for time column like 1246 and I want to insert it in my database like **12:46:00**

Comment: I don't understand. You ask how to insert and get 12:46. But before that you say you already have it when you check. Perhaps some confusion there. Share your code and try to clarify the problem.

Comment: you should use `HH:mm:ss` format (24 hour standard time format)

Comment: @MattiasLindberg In text file I have  text 1246 and want to insert in a column(datatype Time), after insertion when I check inserted value it shows 00:12:46 instead of 12:46:00

Comment: Ok, my mistake. But then it looks like a problem with the import code, can you please share it by updating the question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a trigger Before insertion on table, in which I wanted to insert data from text file. 
`Delimiter $$
Create trigger trg_trantime BEFORE INSERT
 on TransactionTimes 
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       set new.transTime = TIME_FORMAT(new.transTime,'%i:%s:00');
     END;$$
DELIMITER ;`